# mysql when is a view indexed?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was just wondering, when is a view generated/indexed?

I do have quite some data (severl gb) and want read access on views to be fast. Also i'd prefer what writing data isn't slowed down by views. Most likely a manual trigger would be the perfect fit right now  or I'd like the views to be cached if no new data is added. Once a day I import new data which takes about 2h.

Are there any special settings to views to control when they are created/cached?

Comment: From MySQL documentation: `Views are stored queries that when invoked produce a result set. A view acts as a virtual table.`. A view is not a table. A view is a "shortcut" for not having to type tons of `JOIN`s. Therefore, all the rules that apply to queries that contain joined tables apply to views. That means the view has **nothing** to do with writing. It has **nothing** to do with indexes. Tables that are in the view have to do with indexing. Write speed depends on your HDD I/O mostly. Databases like lots of data flushed in a single I/O. Clarify your question.

Comment: It seems you ask about `materialized views` for which there is, unfortunately, no construct available in mysql.